# Privilege View Close Votes - not working

Tags: bug, reputation, uxexchange

I have already reached 250 reputation in UX-StackExchange and Privileges track also shows that privileges has been credited but clicking to view votes does nothing.

Is it because of the fact that my [meta UX](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/) reputation (which still shows 246) is **not yet synced** with [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

If it is, then shouldn't the syncing across networks be an immediate thing?

**Update:** Well now meta and ux reputations are in sync but still I haven't been able to view votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused, since you're talking about two different [privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). At 250 rep you are able to see close votes on your post that has close votes. But the button *close* to the right of the *edit* button is used for casting a close/reopen vote **on your own post**.

[image]

At 1000 reps you can click the vote counter and see up votes and down votes on a post. At 3000 rep you can cast close/reopen votes on any post.

Do you see the close button on this post today? Or do you see it on [your own question at the main site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76949/responsive-vs-adaptive-vs-fixed-size-video-player)?

Comment: ohh now I got it.. I was completely mistaking 250 privilege for 1000 privilege. thanks for clearing the doubt benny

Comment: @exexzian You're welcome :-)